# cannot get a value from a $_GET request

Tags: php, mysql, database, html, request

this is my button that holds a value:

```
<td><a href="viewMore.php?eventID=<?php echo $row['eventID'];?>"><button class="viewMore"> View </button></a></td>
```

this is my php code:

```
<?php
include ('connectDB.php');
$eventID = $_GET['eventID'];
echo $eventID;
?>
```

this is the error message:

> Notice: Undefined index: eventID in
>   /users/c/cakaja/www/astonEvents/viewMore.php on line 4

I am not sure why `$eventID` has no value.

Comment: why it's empty !? we don't no what are you passing to the variable

Comment: viewMore.php?eventID=<?php echo $row['eventID'];?>    this is what im passing, eventID is from the database

Comment: Hey! well what I can say is: make sure there is a value in $row['eventID'] and if you want to make sure everything is working, try to leave the variable with lower case. Example: $_GET['event_id'], so your URL would be: viewMore.php?event_id=123456

Comment: hey! thanks for your response. I am sure that $row[eventID] has a value as it displays in the URL.

Comment: If you are on a test environment, have a var_dump display the eventId as it comes from the row, as well as, the whole $_GET array, so you'll know.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `if(isset($_GET['eventId']))`.

Try Using:

```
<?php

include ('connectDB.php');

if(isset($_GET['eventId'])) {
    $eventID = $_GET['eventID'];
    echo $eventID;
}

?>
```

PHP `isset()` documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Also try using:

```
<?php

include ('connectDB.php');

if(isset($_REQUEST['eventId'])) {
    $eventID = $_REQUEST['eventID'];
    echo $eventID;
}

?>
```

Comment: this got rid of the error message but did not echo anything

Answer (score 0):

If your web server is not configured correctly, you may need to add a / between the file and query strings in the button code:

```
<td><a href="viewMore.php/?eventID=<?php echo $row['eventID']; ?>"><button class="viewMore"> View </button></a></td>
```